# How to translate "Responsive" into Russian?

Tags: перевод, одним-словом

Can you tell me please how can i translate **Responsive** into Russian? 
The context is web-design, and Responsive means that the website adapt itself depending on the device through which it is viewed (pc, tablet, iphone..)

Google Translate give **отзывчивый** but i don't think is the proper translation.

Someone can help me please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use отзывчивый in the mentioned context.

You can use adjective адаптированный/адаптирован instead.

"Наш сайт адаптирован под  автоматическое изменение контента в зависимости от платформы пользователя."

"Наш сайт адаптирован для всех мобильных платформ."

"Наш сайт платформо-независим."

"Наш сайт универсален и работает на любой платформе."

the general definition for such type of the site is "адаптивный сайт"

Comment: Ok, thank you. 
In italian we actually do not translate it and we just say 'responsive'.
If i will use the english word, responsive, will be understood by Russians or is not used at all?

Comment: I am afraid the word "responsive" will be misunderstood by native Russian speaker in the provided context. Replace it with "adaptive site".

Comment: That's okay, it's misunderstood by English speakers too, because "responsive" for web sites already refers to how fast the site responds to requests.

Comment: The word "адаптированный" in this context has a *static* meaning - in other words, emphasized "was made to be responsive". A better word would be "адаптивный". Also: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD

Comment: @johnnyfittizio even if you want to use a foreign word in Russian speech you have to adapt it, such as in "респонсивный" (compare транспарентный). But this word just conveys little meaning for a Russian speaker. They will either try to use their knowledge of English or derive analogy form rare professional terms already borrowed in Russian (such as респондер).

Answer (score 8):

The usual translation in this context is "**адаптивный**" (see the [wikipedia article](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD)), though the translation "**отзывчивый**" is also mentioned in the same article. The discussion page mentions certain [subtle differences](http://viljamis.com/blog/2012/adaptive-vs-responsive-whats-the-difference.php) between the two notions.